# Validation error on associated factory when using FactoryGirl with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to using RSpec and FactoryGirl. I'm trying to add RSpec tests to an existing codebase.

I have the following factories defined:

```
Factory.sequence :email do |n|
  "somebody#{n}@example.com"
end

Factory.sequence :login do |n|
  "inquire#{n}"
end

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.login { Factory.next(:login) }
  f.email { Factory.next(:email) }
  f.password 'inquire_pass'
  f.password_confirmation 'inquire_pass'
  f.first_name 'test'
  f.last_name 'guy'
  f.newsletter true
  f.notify_of_events true
  f.terms_of_service true
end

Factory.define :project do |project|
  project.title               "Example Project Title"
  project.association         :user
  project.association         :provider
  project.association         :project_request
  project.association         :offering
  project.association         :offering_type
end
```

When I try to create a Project factory in my tests, however and assign it to @project:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Charge do
    before(:each) do
        @provider_user = Factory(:user)
        @provider = stub_model(Provider, :user => @provider_user)
        @user = Factory(:user)
        @project_request = stub_model(ProjectRequest)
        @project = Factory(:project, :user => @user, :provider => @provider, :offering_fixed_fee_number => 700,
                                     :project_request_id => @project_request.id)
        @attr = {
          :user_id => @user.id,
          :provider_id => @provider.id,
          :charge_client => "0.01"
        }
        @charge = @project.build_charge(@attr)
    end
```

I get an error message when running the tests indicating that the validations for the associated user have failed:

```
Validation failed: User email can't be blank, User email is too short (minimum is 3 characters), User email does not look like a valid email address., Login can't be blank
```

The relevant validations on the User model are:

```
  validates_presence_of     :login, :email
  validates_uniqueness_of   :login, :email, :case_sensitive => false

  validates_length_of       :login, :within => 5..20   
  validates_format_of       :login, :with => /^[a-z0-9-]+$/i, :message => 'may only contain letters, numbers or a hyphen.'

  validates_length_of       :email, :within => 3..100
  validates_format_of       :email, :with => Authentication.email_regex, :message => 'does not look like a valid email address.'
```

I'm able to create valid User factories (by themselves) with no problem. But when I try to create projects that have a User association, and specify the associated User as the factory user I created earlier, the validations on that User fail. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Thanks very much,

Dean Richardson

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because `factory` param in `association` method is missing:

```
Factory.define :project do |project|
  project.association :user, :factory => :user
  ...
end
```

But in this case it could be written more easily:

```
Factory.define :project do |project|
  project.user
  ...
end
```

See [Factory Girl. Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)